# Creating custom graphs with elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed ELK tools but somehow I wanna take the data from elasticsearch and created some graphs with the data on my own instead of using Kibana. I have notified there are some tools like elasticsearch.js but I couldn't get any ideas on how to start it out, i.e. what should I do in order to extract those data and customize my graphs with js.

Would anyone who have previous experience can share about it.

Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked on such a graph, but I guess it should not be very complicated to build. Since, elasticsearch does provide REST API and returns a JSON response, this JSON response can be handled by writing a custom toolkit which can represent that in format you want to.

There are toolkits available to handle JSON visualization like Protovis or json-stat. May be you can look at those, and even if nothing exists you can very well write your own toolkit